# How to integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xe^{-2\lambda |x|} dx$?

Tags: integration, exponential-function, improper-integrals

I need to integrate
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}   xe^{-2\lambda |x|} dx$$
We are given that $\lambda$ is positive and real
This is my attempt
$$\int_{-\infty}^{0}  x e^{2\lambda x} dx+ \int_{0}^{\infty}   xe^{-2\lambda x} dx$$
Using u-sub $u =  {2\lambda x}$ and integrating by parts
$$\frac{1}{2\lambda}\int_{-\infty}^{0}  ue^{u} du+ \frac{1}{2\lambda}\int_{0}^{\infty}   ue^{-u} du$$
$$= \frac{1}{2\lambda}(-1+1) = 0$$
But it seems wrong to me

Comment: It's correct, notice that your function is odd

Comment: What does an odd function mean? Ty so much anyway

Comment: See Peter answer below

Comment: This question was in physics where  x is a hermitian operator and we had to take its expection value but I was wondering how can the expectation value or mean be zero

Comment: There is an added complication because the integral is improper. Note that the integrals would not cancel if each side does not converge.

Comment: Expectation can be zero in many cases. This is quite normal. Imagine a simple experiment (discrete case): you have a 6-sided die labeled with 1,2,3,-3,-2,-1. You roll it 6*N times and note the sum you got. The expected value for this sum is zero.

Comment: Thanks it is more clear now.:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This derivation is correct.

You can also just notice that the function under the integral is odd i.e.
$$f(-x)=-f(x)$$ for every $x$.

So... of course the definite integral from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$
if it is well defined (i.e. if it converges) will be equal to zero.

See also: [Even and Odd functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions)

It is also important to note that the two improper integrals of $f(x)$ (from minus infinity to zero and from zero to plus infinity) converge. Why is this important? Because there are odd functions for which the integral from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ is not zero but is undefined. A very simple example is $f(x)=x$ which is such an odd function.

[Integral of f(x)=x from minus infinity to plus infinity](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20x%20from%20-inf%20to%20inf)

Comment: You have to mention that the improper integrals converge. Otherwise they do not cancel.

Comment: @Miguel Yes, thanks, that's correct.

Answer (score 4):

The integral has to vanish as the integrand is an odd function. Your approach is correct but because of my first point no calculus was needed here.

Comment: You have to mention that the improper integrals converge. Otherwise they do not cancel.

Comment: You are right about that, thanks.